# build NPOS EVM commpatible chain

Tags: staking, frontier, evm, election, npos

What's the best project setup to build an NPoS and EVM Compatible chain at this moment?
Which version/branch of polkadot release to use? such as polkadot-v0.9.22 or polkadot-v0.9.18?
Use ORML or Frontiers's EVM-Pallets?

It looks to me any version above polkadot-v0.9.19 has the same issue. Adding EVM pallet to runtime and adding genesis accounds to genesis config causes StakingElection.failed and era stagnates and never changes, election never occurs, line in [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/npos-with-aura-no-planned-era) question.

EDIT 1:
I have implemented NPoS using ElectionProviderMultiPhase and pallet Staking, and EVM using frontier's EVM pallets using branches polkadot-v0.9.22 version. Here are the logs and the error that shows up.

[image: terminal logs]

[image: explorer logs]

Comment: you can use any branch of polkadot and use same branch of frontier suppose if you are using polkadot-v0.9.22 then use the same branch of frontier also.

Comment: I did so, but it looks like the StakingElection.failed error still exists in all 0.9.2* versions, and it looks like a compatibility issue between frontier's EVM pallets and pallets used to build NPoS runtimes.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaDar you have not asked a clear and concise question above. Please update your post to be something that can be directly answered else, we will need to close this post.

Comment: I would like to know if a standalone chain can be NPoS and have EVM compatability. Because it looks that is not possible for versions of polkadot-v0.9.2*. @ShawnTabrizi

Comment: Ability to run the EVM and which consensus you use are not related. So yes, it is possible. It looks like you have not set up your staking correctly, so you need to simplify and clarify your question to solve that.

Comment: How many validator candidates you have (`staking.validators`) and how many validators you want? (`staking.validatorCount`)?